# Is there a result on the maximum value of the dual variable for a parametric LP in terms of the parameters of the LP?

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am working with a linear program of the following kind:

\begin{array}[t]{l}
\min c^{\top} x\\
s.t.\\
\quad A x = b\\
\quad 0 \le x \le x^{u}
\end{array}

Can I find out the upper limit of the shadow prices (dual variables) of this linear program as a function of $b$, $c$ and $x^u$? The upper limit need not be tight, but as long as I know that the value bounds the dual variables, it serves my purpose. It can be assumed that $c$, $b$ and $x^u$ are always so chosen that the linear program is bounded and feasible. If it helps, it can be assumed that for all possible values of the parameters, the objective of the linear program can take a value between $f^l$ and $f^u$.